# Indexing for joins in mysql database

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join

Had a quick question about joins in mysql and indexing. If I had 2 tables:

```
table1
 id
 name

table2
 table1id
 table2title
```

And I join table2 and table1 using id and table1id would I add a index to id on table1 and table1id in table2? Or would I just add an index to one of the tables? Im using MySQL with MyISAM version 5.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `table1`.`id` is a primary key, then you don't need to index it. (Primary keys are automatically indexed)
If not, then you'll need to index `table1`.`id` and `table2`.`table1id`

Use "EXPLAIN" in you selects to see what indexes you are hitting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add an index on both `id` columns (as another poster said, `primary` columns are indexed). Indices allow MySQL to [quickly locate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) the row in a data file, instead of reading sequentially.

If you need rows from both tables given an id, index both tables for optimal performance. Else, the initial clause (`SELECT...WHERE`) will run quickly, and the `JOIN` will be slow (or vice versa), resulting in a slow query.